# unset compass single-text-shadow()

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Is there a way to unset or remove the [text-shadow effect](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/text-shadow/) of the compass function ?

e.g. i want to set the text shadow globally for all header elements and then eliminate it for certain cases.

```
h2 { @include single-text-shadow($blue, 1px, 1px, 0); }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As in CSS, simply declare `none`:

```
.specific h2 { @include single-text-shadow(none); }
```